# CakePhp: model recursive associations and find

Tags: php, cakephp, model, belongs-to

I've some trouble with a find() on a model on CakePhp.

I have three model relationed in this way:

Project(some_fields, item_id)
------belongsTo-----> Item(some_fields, item_id)
------belongsTo-----> User(some_fields campi, nickname)

I need to do a find() and retrieve all fields from project, a field from Item and the nickname field from User. This is my code:

```
$this->set('projects', $this->Project->find('all', array('recursive' => 2)));
```

but my output doesn't contains the user object.
I've tried with Containable behaviour but the output is the same. What is broken?

Many many Thanks

Peter

Comment: Unless you have a typo here, you don't seem to have a `user_id` field in the `items` table.

Comment: can you post your containable array (code) or the condition that you have applied in containable fetching of model fields ?

Answer (score 1):

Your approach generates too many queries. You may want to reduce their quantity by binding and unbinding models. See details [here](http://mark-story.com/posts/view/using-bindmodel-to-get-to-deep-relations).

Answer (score 1):

Set Your model properly or try with join

```
$this->Project->recursive = -1;
$this->Project->find('all', array(
   'joins'=>array(
      array(
        'table'=>'item',
        'alias'=>'Item',
        'type'=>'INNER',
        'conditions'=>array(
           'Item.id=Project.item_id'
             )
          ),
       array(
         'table'=>'user',
         'alias'=>'User',
         'type'=>'INNER',
         'conditions'=>array(
            'User.id=Item.user_id'
         )
      )
   ),
   'fields'=>array(
     //necessary
   ),
   'conditions'=>array(
     //if any
   );
```

Answer (score 1):

Project.php Model file should be as below

```
<?php
App::uses('AppModel','Model');
/*
*
* Project Model
*
*/
Class Project extends AppModel{

/*
*
* actsAs Behaviour
*
*/
    public $actsAs = array('Containable');

/*
*
* belongsTO association
*
*/  
    public $belongsTo = array(
        'Item' => array(
            'className' => 'Item',
            'foreignKey' => 'project_id',
            )
        );
}
?>
```

Item.php Model file should be as below

```
<?php
App::uses('AppModel','Model');
/*
*
* Item Model
*
*/
Class Item extends AppModel{

/*
*
* actsAs Behaviour
*
*/
    public $actsAs = array('Containable');

/*
*
* belongsTO association
*
*/  
    public $belongsTo = array(
        'User' => array(
            'className' => 'User',
            'foreignKey' => 'item_id',
            )
        );
/*
*
* hasMany association
*
*/  
    public $hasMany = array(
        'Project' => array(
            'className' => 'Project',
            'foreignKey' => 'project_id',
            )
        );  
}
?>
```

User.php Model file should be as below

```
<?php
App::uses('AppModel','Model');
/*
*
* User Model
*
*/
Class User extends AppModel{

/*
*
* actsAs Behaviour
*
*/
    public $actsAs = array('Containable');


/*
*
* hasMany association
*
*/  
    public $hasMany = array(
        'Item' => array(
            'className' => 'Item',
            'foreignKey' => 'item_id',
            )
        );  
}
?>
```

You can try with below code in the controller.

```
<?php
$contain = array('Item' => array('User'));
$this->set('projects', $this->Project->find('all', array('contain' => $contain)));
?>
```